# Transfer learning on data with lesser target labels than that of the pretrained classifier

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, transfer-learning

Let's say there is a pre-trained model (base_model) that is already trained using a large dataset to predict 7 human emotions such as

```
'Anger', 'Disgust', 'Fear', 'Happiness', 'Sadness', 'Surprise','Neutral'
```

Now, in order to build a transfer learned model, I will remove the last layer of "base_model", freeze their weights and make them non-trainable, and then add a fine tuned layer of my own which is trainable.

I want to know how to train this newly compiled model "model_finetuned" on a smaller dataset containing only 3 out of 7 emotions i.e

```
'Anger', 'Sadness', 'Surprise'
```

Any help or suggestions in the form of a Python code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly explained, you could freeze the preteined model weigths and fine-tuning adding fully connected layers at the end of the model.

There are two ways to leverage a pre-trained network: feature extraction and fine-tuning.

- **Feature extraction**: consists of using the representations learned by a previous network to extract interesting features from new samples. These features are then run through a new classifier, which is trained from scratch. (Cold be the last Fully connected Layer)
- **Fine-tuning**: consists in unfreezing a few of the top layers of a frozen model base used for feature extraction, and jointly training both the newly added part of the model.

Example with pretrained vgg16:

```
#Load pretrained vgg16 network
from torchvision.models import vgg16

num_classes = 3
pretrained_model = vgg16(pretrained=True)
pretrained_model.eval()
pretrained_model.to(device)

#Extracting the first part of the model
feature_extractor = pretrained_model.features

#Define feature classifier
feature_classifier = nn.Sequential(
nn.Linear(4*4*512,256),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Linear(256, num_classes))

#
model = nn.Sequential(
feature_extractor,
nn.Flatten(),
feature_classifier)
```

As you can see, you must specify the output of your model in the last fully connected layer. In your case would be (num_classes = 3).

Comment: The code that you provided is written in PyTorch, although correct, the writer may not know how to adapt it.

Comment: Thanks @mgrau but I think based on your code, the model will make predictions only for those 3 classes and not for all 7

Comment: Hi @PrathameshMohite , it is true that I understood the problem wrongly as my solution only will be useful to classify between the 3 classes.

On the other hand, one solution for your problem, could be using per-class weighted loss function as you should give lower importance to the classes you are re-training because of the higher number of training samples of this 3 classes in comparison to the others.

With Pytorch Framework you can specify a manual rescaling weight for each class.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a code I worked with some days ago using Tensorflow Keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense

num_classes= 3

# Include the path of the weights for the pretrained model
resnet_weights_path='imagenet'

# Create your model
model= Sequential()

# Include the pre-trained model. In this case, ResNet50
model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False,pooling='avg',weights=resnet_weights_path ))

# Add as many extra layers as you need, according to you problem
# You can also try it directly

# Add the final layer that makes predictions. Suit yourself with the activation function 
model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax'))

# Don't train the pre-trained model
model.layers[0].trainable=False

# Compile your model according to your needs
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now your model is ready to be trained.